# PHP mail / PEAR mail

Tags: php

On my directory website I have a "send email" functionality. This lets a user submit an enquiry to a company. A copy of this enquiry is also sent to my inbox.

A few months ago I noticed that I had stopped receiving the email copy to my inbox. So I investigated this and it turned out that my web host was no longer allowing sending external emails using the PHP mail function.

When I questioned this I was told that I would need to start using a third party mail plugin, and I was recommended to use PEAR.

So I converted my PHP script to use PEAR and managed to get it working on my site. All was good until until one day I thought it would be a good idead to switch to PHP 5.3 on my web host. A few days later I noticed that I had again stopped receiving the email copy to my inbox.

So again I investigated this and found that it was broken. I was told that I would need to revert back to PHP 5.2 for this to work. So basically that's what I had to do to make it work again.

My question is, how can I know when the mail functionality is broken as soon as it breaks? During the time it takes for me to realise it's broken, several enquiries could be being sent from the site which aren't actually going anywhere.

And secondly should I stick with PEAR or are there any better alternatives out there?

Comment: I would look around for a new host. And yes, there are better alternatives than PEAR. There is *always* better alternatives than PEAR.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of alternatives to PEAR::Mail.  However first I have to address the question of whether your goal is to pay your hosting company so that they arbitrarily break your site and subsequently, your business?  I'm not sure why anyone would pay to be on a habitrail wheel of fail, and pay for that.

With that said this package http://swiftmailer.org/ has become very popular and is bundled as part of the symfony2 framework, which is an excellent endorsement of its functionality and support for the latest/greatest features in PHP.

Prior to that, http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ was a very popular package.

As for detecting whether your mail is working, the only way to do that is to have an automated test job that sends you an email every day, or at whatever periodicity you want.  If you don't get that email, you know that there is an issue that requires investigation.